# Error while getting active subscriptions status from Google Play API

Tags: php, android, in-app-purchase, authorization, subscription

By requesting the Google Play API, I am getting the refresh token and then the Access Token. But when I request the Google Play API Status with the above mentioned Access Token, I am getting the following error :

```
["error"]=>
array(3) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["domain"]=>
      string(6) "global"
      ["reason"]=>
      string(9) "forbidden"
      ["message"]=>
      string(9) "Forbidden"
    }
  }
  ["code"]=>
  int(403)
  ["message"]=>
  string(9) "Forbidden"
```

What could be the possible reason?